# "Strictly positive" in Agda

Tags: haskell, types, interpreter, semantics, agda

I'm trying to encode some denotational semantics into Agda based on a program I wrote in Haskell.

```
data Value = FunVal (Value -> Value)
           | PriVal Int
           | ConVal Id [Value]
           | Error  String
```

In Agda, the direct translation would be;

```
data Value : Set where
    FunVal : (Value -> Value) -> Value
    PriVal : ℕ -> Value
    ConVal : String -> List Value -> Value
    Error  : String -> Value
```

but I get an error relating to the FunVal because;

> Value is not strictly positive, because it occurs to the left of an
>   arrow in the type of the constructor FunVal in the definition of
>   Value.

What does this mean? Can I encode this in Agda? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in PHOAS, explained by Chlipala [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/papers/PhoasICFP08/PhoasICFP08.ps).

Comment: Thanks. I've had a little play with that since.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[HOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_abstract_syntax) doesn't work in Agda, because of this:

```
apply : Value -> Value -> Value
apply (FunVal f) x = f x
apply _ x = Error "Applying non-function"

w : Value
w = FunVal (\x -> apply x x)
```

Now, notice that evaluating `apply w w` gives you `apply w w` back again.  The term `apply w w` has no normal form, which is a no-no in agda.  Using this idea and the type:

```
data P : Set where
    MkP : (P -> Set) -> P
```

We can derive a contradiction.

One of the ways out of these paradoxes is only to allow strictly positive recursive types, which is what Agda and Coq choose.  That means that if you declare:

```
data X : Set where
    MkX : F X -> X
```

That `F` must be a strictly positive functor, which means that `X` may never occur to the left of any arrow.  So these types are strictly positive in `X`:

```
X * X
Nat -> X
X * (Nat -> X)
```

But these are not:

```
X -> Bool
(X -> Nat) -> Nat  -- this one is "positive", but not strictly
(X * Nat) -> X
```

So in short, no you can't represent your data type in Agda.  You can use de Bruijn encoding to get a term type you can work with, but usually the evaluation function needs some sort of "timeout" (generally called "fuel"), e.g. a maximum number of steps to evaluate, because Agda requires all functions to be total.  [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/gallais/303cfcfe053fbc63eb61) due to @gallais that uses a coinductive partiality type to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had an inkling about something like this but didn't entirely understand.

Comment: "the simply typed lambda calculus [...] has terms without normal forms" Is that true? I thought the simply typed lambda calculus (as opposed to the untyped lambda calculus or the more complexly typed variations of the lambda calculus) always reduces to a normal form (unless you add the fixpoint operator as a built-in), which is why it is not turing-complete.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry. Still trying to get my understanding of this. By fixpoint as built-in, do you mean leaving the fixpoint operator as a non-evaluated term rather than part of the evaluation function?

Comment: @Jason: By built-in I simply mean that you can not define fixpoint as a function in the simply typed lambda-calculus (while you can in the untyped lambda calculus), so it has to be built into the language as an operator (i.e. you have a keyword `fix` and special rules to evaluate expressions using the keyword).

Comment: It's worth adding that you can actually embed the untyped lambda calculus into Agda by evaluating it in the partiality monad, which models possible non-termination with a possibly infinite number of discrete steps.

Comment: @copumpkin I would love to see that comment expanded into an answer of it's own. How would you use the partiality monad to embed untyped lambda calculus?